# Monitor folder and delete file if exists/created

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I would like to monitor a folder and every time a file of specific name is created, or if it simply exists, I would like to delete it. I would like to keep things native to Windows 7 to avoid having to install other software/packages. I believe Powershell along with FileSystemWatcher would be able to do this but I've no experience with either.

The specific application is that my employer regularly (~90 mins) pings the folder 'C:\Windows\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds' on my office PC and adds 'backgroundDefault.jpg', with some advertising on. I would like to delete this file to keep the generic windows default one. I tried creating a file named 'background1920x1080.jpg' as I understand Windows will preferentially load file with a resolution in the name, but it seems 1920x1080 is not one of these recognized resolutions.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: First, think.. will I piss off my IT?  ALWAYS think this one through. There are so many other ways to solve this.  One possible way... Are you a local admin?  Lock the folder down so only "administrators" can write to it.  Then delete the file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use File System Watcher to monitor and take action of files and folders, it's a common thing and shown in the help files and many examples and pre-built scripts all over the web ...

Search for: 'powershell filesystem watcher'

> FileSystemWatcherClass 
>   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8
>
> Tracking Changes to a Folder Using PowerShell

```
$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$FileSystemWatcher | Get-Member -Type Properties, Event 

$FileSystemWatcher.Path = "C:\Users\proxb\Desktop\DropBox"

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher  -EventName Created  -Action {

    $Object = "{0} was  {1} at {2}" -f $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath,
    $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType,
    $Event.TimeGenerated

    $WriteHostParams = @{
        ForegroundColor = 'Green'
        BackgroundColor = 'Black'
        Object          = $Object
    }
    Write-Host @WriteHostParams
}
```

> https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/09/24/changes-to-a-folder-using-powershell.aspx
>
> Using a FileSystemWatcher from PowerShell
>   http://www.mobzystems.com/code/using-a-filesystemwatcher-from-powershell

… even videos on the topic...

> https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell+file+system+watcher

... as well as already in the MS TechNet and MS PowerShell Gallery …

> Powershell FileSystemWatcher
>
> This script uses the .net FileSystemWatcher class to subscribe to
>   'create', 'change' and 'delete' events on files or folders in the NTFS
>   filesystem.It can be used to monitor a folder or folders, and can be
>   modified to perform any action upon the triggering of these events.
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b/file/42206/1/FileSystemWatcher.ps1

... but ditto to what Senor CMasMas said. Don't just randomly make these types of decisions without a plan and notification.

Also, this also says you are new to PowerShell in general

So, you really absolutely need to ramp up on it first, you tube is your friend for this. Never ever do destructive actions with an approach you do not fully understand. Never randomly run anyone's code, no matter who gives it to you or where you get it from, unless you fully understand the ramifications of using it. You can destroy your system and or environment if you are not careful.